# Gnuplot group date by year/month

Tags: gnuplot

Is my first time using gnuplot and my data file `data.csv` have the following content

```
2017-05-28,50000
2017-07-13,100
2017-07-14,3217
2017-01-23,2052
2017-01-24,1954
2017-01-25,1664
```

Now I'm tryting to plot using the following setup

```
set title 'My First Graph'
set ylabel 'Total per day'
set xlabel 'Date'
set grid
set term png
set datafile separator ","
set output 'graph.png'
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'
set format x "%Y-%m"
plot 'data.csv'
```

First I got a `line 10: Bad format character` which I dont understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `set xdata time` and `plot` with specifying the two columns explicitly:

```
set title 'My First Graph'
set ylabel 'Total per day'
set xlabel 'Date'
set grid
set datafile separator ","
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'
set format x "%Y-%m"
set xdata time
plot 'data.csv' using 1:2
```

gives

[image]